# Metric for queue size

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

Using spring stream with rabbitmq binder. We are wanting to have a metric for our queue sizes. What is the best way to implement a metric for queue size?

I have attemped to use the annotation @EnableIntegrationManagement...but I'm not seeing our output channels Counter metric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the size of the queue(s) on the RabbitMQ broker, there is nothing in the client application that provides that out of the box. Why would you expect `@EnableIntegrationManagement` to help, especially with regard to the output channel?

You can either call the REST API against the RabbitMQ management plugin, or you can use the `RabbitAdmin` and call `getQueueProperties(queueName)`.

Comment: How would I go about getting a rabbitadmin bean? I can see a rabbitadmin bean when I hit the beans actuator of our app, but when I try to have spring autowire it, but I get a not found exception.

Comment: IIRC, you have to autowire it as `AmqpAdmin`.

Comment: Yeah, using AmqpAdmin fixed the autowiring. Now I'm getting "Connection refused (Connection refused)" .  We are running on PCF and all the connection magic happens for us. Was hoping that the RabbitAdmin would be all setup

Comment: fix it with this: '@Configuration
public class RabbitmqConfig extends AbstractCloudConfig {

 @Bean
 public ConnectionFactory rbc() {
  return connectionFactory().rabbitConnectionFactory();
 }
 
}'